# Printing dictionary as tree like structure

Tags: python

I have below nested dictionary with parent and child relations

```
dict_tree = {'A': {'b': {'c': {'d': {}, 'e': {'f': {}}}}}}
```

Where A is root and any node which does not have leaf its value will be {} (d and f are such nodes)

I would like to print this in tree like structure as below:

```
A
|-b
    |-c
        |-d
        |-e
            |-f
```

I tried below library https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/importer/dictimporter.html

```
dict_tree = {'A': {'b': {'c': {'d': {}, 'e': {'f': {}}}}}}

from anytree.importer import DictImporter
from anytree import RenderTree
importer = DictImporter()
root = importer.import_(dict_tree)

print(RenderTree(root))
```

But the output is:

```
AnyNode(A={'b': {'c': {'d': {}, 'e': {'f': {}}}}})
```

It looks like it is accepting the different format of dictionary (documentation is not super helpful).

Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a recursive function that "walks" a dict-of-dicts.

```
dict_tree = {"A": {"b": {"c": {"d": {}, "e": {"f": {}}}}}}


def print_tree_level(dct, level=0):
    for key, value in dct.items():
        print(
            "    " * (level - 1),
            "|-" if level else "",
            key,
            sep="",
        )
        print_tree_level(value, level + 1)


print_tree_level(dict_tree)
```

will print out

```
A
|-b
    |-c
        |-d
        |-e
            |-f
```

which looks to me to be your exact desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use json module

```py
import json

print(json.dumps(dict_tree, indent=2))
```

The output would be:

```json
{
  "A": {
    "b": {
      "c": {
        "d": {},
        "e": {
          "f": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The output doesn't look like OP's desired output.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the documentation and it seems like it is expecting the following format:

```
{'a': 'A', 'children': [{'a': 'B', 'children': [{'a': 'C', 'children': [{ 'a' : 'D'}, {'b': 'E', 'children': { 'a' : 'F'}}]}]}]}
```

NOTE: I converted the chars from your example to uppercase to make it easy to distinguish between the input format required by anytree and your example.

If you wish to use the library then you will have to reformat the dictionary according to the desired format.

If you wish to write your own code then you can for instance to operate on the exact dictionary you provided then this might work:

```
def print_node(node, lvl):
  if len(node.keys()) == 0:
    return
  prefix = ' ' * lvl
  if lvl > 0:
    prefix = prefix + '|-'
  for item in node.items():
    print(f'{prefix}{item[0]}')
    print_node(item[1], lvl + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't too bothered by the output format (i.e. it doesn't look like the format you presented), you can use the json library.

```
import json
x = json.dumps(dict_tree, indent=2)
print(x)
```